# How to check for the latest version of java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I want to make a java-based GUI tool that checks for the latest version of java available online,and compares it to the version currently installed

I already know how to check for the version currently installed on the machine

I don't know about the part where you check for the version available online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web based **[Java Tester](http://www.javatester.org/version.html)** does what you want to do.

The author of the Java Tester keeps track of the latest version manually.  I think you would have to do the same.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to do,but in a swing app,thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into java web start for deploying your application? It will automatically perform version checks and perform the installation if a new version is needed.

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp

Comment: No,and I want to write code that checks for the version myself,I'm not familiar with the JNLP technology

Comment: I should have known. Your username suggests that you might have a strong fear of JNLP technology :)

Comment: JNLP checks the application's version, not Java's version.

Comment: I want to say that via the JNLP file, you can also specify that the application requires a particular version of java. If that version is not installed, jnlp will either download it or direct the user to a site where they can download and install it.

Comment: A particular version of java doesn't mean that it'll be the latest available,right?