# Oracle or 3rd party service for determining 'latest Java version'

Tags: applet, java, auto-update

Is there a service available that responds with the latest version of Java that's available?

I'm writing system check for an application that uses applets. As part of the check I'd like to inform users if a new version of Java is available for download. Is there any online service that simply responds with the version number for the latest Java version?

Comment: +1, Great question IMHO.

Comment: When you install Java on a Windows box it will check whether you have the latest version and if not offer to install it. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, we really don't want to have each java application to perform its own tests of the system...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260803/how-to-check-for-the-latest-version-of-java

Comment: Set up your own service. Do not forget to add google ads ;-)

Comment: If you are making applets to be used outside of a very small, very walled, garden of users, you are in for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 4):

How about a different strategy of 'leave it to the manufacturer'?

The JRE is configured by default to be auto-updating to the latest version Oracle considers to be stable enough for general use. Best leave it to the auto-update feature.

### Run-time testing

Of course, there is always [How do I test whether Java is working on my computer?](http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp)

#### FireFox

> **An old version of Java has been detected on your system.**
>
> Update Java by clicking the button below:

A polite way of saying 'no plug-in found for FF'.

#### Chrome

[image: Update Available]

### User Friendly

But ultimately either way, leave it to the end-user's discretion as to what version to use, and whether to update.

Comment: (+1) Good point. I'd find it rather annoying if I had twenty apps, and all of them felt it their duty to keep me posted on Oracle's releases (especially if I had reasons to not upgrade the JRE right away).